# How do I compute phase and amplitude of a sinusoidal by correlating it with a sine and cosine?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

I have an incoming sinusoidal with a known frequency. I understand that one can compute it's phase and amplitude by computing it's correlation with a sine and a cosine. How would I do this using numpy?

Or maybe there is a better way to do this? Looking at [this here](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs206/archive/spring02/lab.dir/Lab3/lab3_v3_0_release.pdf), but I don't know how to do the computation in numpy.

Comment: In which form do you have the sinusoid? In the form of points ,I guess ?

Comment: Yes. I have sample values at regular intervals for an entire cycle.

Comment: Do you have some special points(peak point or zero amplitude points because then it would be easier

Comment: Well, I could scan the samples for zero crossings, or max values, but they are not guaranteed to be present. Take a look at the link I added to the question. I would like to implement the computation described in the article in numpy. Need some help with that.

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317667/frequency-domain-of-a-sine-wave-with-frequency-1000hz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One convenient method would be to take advantage of Euler's formula `e^(i phi) = cos phi + i sin phi`:

```
def get_cos_params(samples):
    N = len(samples)
    x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
    template = np.exp(1j * x)
    corr = 2 / N * template@samples
    R = np.abs(corr)
    phi = np.log(corr).imag
    return R, phi
```

Example:

```
N = np.random.randint(10, 1000)
phi = np.random.uniform(-np.pi, np.pi)
R = np.random.uniform(0.1, 10)
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, N, endpoint=False)
signal = R * np.cos(x-phi)
R_recon, phi_recon = get_cos_params(signal)
print(np.isclose(R, R_recon), np.isclose(phi, phi_recon))
# True True
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining what's going on here? I would really appreciate it if you could clarify what you are doing conceptually, and maybe annotate some lines in the answer with comments saying what is happening. Also - I get a syntax error on "template@samples".

Comment: @Ziffusion You must be on an old python version. Either upgrade or replace all `x@y` with `np.dot(x, y)`. Re what is happening, conceptually. Going by your question I naturally assumed that you have already grasped the concept and only needed an example implementation in order to get up to speed with numpy. I've mentioned Euler's formula. Once you are aware of that the code should be pretty close to self-explanatory:

Comment: Step 1 Use Euler's formula to create a combined cosine and sine template with the correct sampling rate. Step 2 Multiply with the signal and compute the "integral". Step 3 translate the integral value to polar coordinates and use the fact that these actually are the amplitude and phase. Please try to identify these steps in the code yourself. If you get stuck in the process I'll be happy to help you out but you are supposed to make some effort yourself first.

Comment: Thanks. I am an engineer and should know this better. But been futzing with software for 30 years now, and all of this stuff has kind of faded away. Am diving back into it now. Thanks for the pointers. I think the link that I have in the question actually has some great context.

Comment: If you have some time (and the inclination), can you chat with me so I can ask you a few questions? You seem to know what you are talking about, and it'll just get me there faster. Stackoverflow has chat I believe.

Comment: @Ziffusion yeah why not. Now where is that move to chat nag when you need it? I think we can just keep using comments and it will pop up soon.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190559/ziffusion-numpy