# Frequency domain of a sine wave with frequency 1000Hz

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

I'm starting DSP on Python and I'm having some difficulties:
I'm trying to define a sine wave with frequency 1000Hz

I try to do the FFT and find its frequency with the following piece of code:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sampling_rate = int(10e3)
n = int(10e3)

sine_wave = [100*np.sin(2 * np.pi * 1000 * x/sampling_rate) for x in range(0, n)]

s = np.array(sine_wave)

print(s)

plt.plot(s[:200])
plt.show()

s_fft = np.fft.fft(s)
frequencies = np.abs(s_fft)
plt.plot(frequencies)
plt.show()
```

So first plot makes sense to me.
Second plot (FFT) shows two frequencies:
i)  1000Hz, which is the one I set at the beggining
ii) 9000Hz, unexpectedly
[freqeuncy domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRyxA.png)

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted part of the question.  I'll delete that comment.

Comment: Your sampling rate is 10000, so the [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) is 5000.  That is the highest possible frequency in your discrete sample.  What you called 9000 Hz is actually -1000 Hz.  You can use [`numpy.fft.fftfreq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html) to find the frequencies associated with the Fourier coefficients returned by `numpy.fft.fft`, e.g. `numpy.fft.fftfreq(len(s_fft), d=1/sampling_rate)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your data do not respect [Shannon criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem). you do not set a correct frequencies axis.

It's easier also to use *rfft* rather than *fft* when the signal is real.

Your code can be adapted like :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sampling_rate = 10000
n = 10000
signal_freq = 4000 # must be < sampling_rate/2 
amplitude = 100

t=np.arange(0,n/sampling_rate,1/sampling_rate)
sine_wave = amplitude*np.sin(2 * np.pi *signal_freq*t) 
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t[:30],sine_wave[:30],'ro')

spectrum = 2/n*np.abs(np.fft.rfft(sine_wave))
frequencies = np.fft.rfftfreq(n,1/sampling_rate)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(frequencies,spectrum)
plt.show()
```

Output :
[image]

There is no information loss, even if a human eye can be troubled by the temporal representation.

Comment: Yeah I see now I should limit my frequency axis to half the sampling rate. And thanks for the extra code it works great.